# Copy files into Android/Java project folder on runtime

Tags: java, android, file

From my reading, I know for sure that one can not copy a file and paste it into any of the android/java project folders (such as, src, assets, etc). But can it be possible if I create custom folder under project root ? Will it still have read only permission ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about modifying the content of APK file. If you want to do that then you cannot. You can only copy any file from APK and past it on any other location but you will require permission to access that directory

Comment: JaiSoni: Yes, your are right. But it does not have to be an APK. I can work with JAR. But just not sure how to modify content of an APK or JAR during runtime. There are posts where developers are suggesting to use ClassLoader. I am not sure if that is a good solution.